# Assembly Dependency using NDepend

Tags: ndepend

I install .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 in my machine. I write a small .NET 2.0 program (contains just one line Console output). When I check assembly dependency using NDepend, it shows my program is depending on .NET 4.0 assembly(mscorlib 4.0) instead of .NET 2.0 assembly(mscorlib 2.0).
Thanks,
ANT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you just need to update the .NET Fx targeted in the *NDepend's Project Properties > Code to Analyze > Folders that contains Application and Third-Party assemblies*, as shown below. By default, NDepend choose the higher installed .NET Fx on the machine.

[image]

Comment: It works find for me. But why do we need to choose .NET version. Manifest already contain reference assembly information, right?

Comment: More flexibility + it could happen that some application or tiers assemblies reference different runtime versions.